# French residence permit

Tags: paperwork, french-citizens

I used to live in France with my son who is a French citizen but moved back to my country 13 yrs ago, I had a resident card which has long expired. I moved back to France 3 months ago with my son and two kids for school and medical attention. I have submitted my documents to the *préfecture* for renewal but they said it might take several months and no timeline were given as they still have backlog from 6 months back.

My question is this: I came on a 1-month short-stay visa which has expired, I want to know if I can apply for school whilst in France here, so that I can be doing something before my file is attended to. My kids have started school and I am just idle because I don't have any valid documents yet.

Comment: Apply for school like some university or lifelong learning of some sort? I recommend trying to approach a non-profit offering advice on immigration matters like GISTI or the Cimade, your situation is not trivial, even your application could be challenging. I understand why you might want to do something productive in the meantime but you should also worry about the risk of being denied residence or being forced to leave (having a French son attending school usually prevents that but your son's age and the interruption could make things tricky).